# i want to change status depending on user actions on the page in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have three  tables in my database.one is requirements,candidates and status..

Status table:

```
INSERT INTO `status` (`status_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'post'),
(2, 'viewed'),
(3, 'working'),
(4, 'candidates_posted'),
(5, 'interview_on'),
(6, 'finalized'),
(7, 'offer_released'),
(8, 'joined'),
(9, 'invoice_raised'),
(10,    'closed');
```

I have this status_id in requirements table..and in candidates also i have status_id.

What i want to do is when user post requirement i need to change the status in requirements table changed to post..

And after vendor post candidates..that time also need to change the status to candidates posted...and user has to see in the frontend like candidates posted..

How will we do that...i don't have any idea..
Can anyone help me..
Thank you.

Comment: How about showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: i just created table for status..i gave that status id in all the tables..i have no idea on this one..my client gave this requirement..please help me..if u have any idea

Comment: when user send requirement..that time vendor has to know that user send one requirement..the above all status actions need to display in the front end..depending on user actions on the page..